# How to generate an OpenAPI from a Spring app without running the app?

Tags: spring-boot, openapi-generator, springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin

I can run a Spring Boot application and then use the `springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin` artifact to generate an OpenAPI spec.

However, is there also a way to generate the spec without running the application first?

I currently want to generate the spec in a GitHub Action and a direct way would simplify this a lot.

Answer (score 1):

To generate OpenAPI with `springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin` you can add `integration-test` goal and run `mvn verify` to generate json/yaml spec after tests. (https://springdoc.org/plugins.html)

Unfortunately, it starts your app and calls OpenAPI endpoint. If your app has startup dependencies (configuration properties, database, etc...) then you have two options:

1. Run your dependencies in docker container before running `mvn verify`. Also you need to configure your properties to use docker hosts and ports.
2. More elegant solution is to create different profile, for example `openapi` and disable database autoconfigurations by using `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = ...)`. To disable component beans, you can use `@ComponentScan` and custom `TypeFilter` which would for example completely exclude Service and Configuration layer from injecting to a context (Because only Controller layer is needed to generate OpenAPI spec). If you will exclude beans which Controller layer depends on then you need to make them as non- required. You can do it by adding `@Autowired(required = false)` for each declaration or it is better to do it for all excluded beans and only for `openapi` profile, for this you can use `QualifierAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver` and override `isRequired` method where you can specify all your excluded beans for which you need to return `false`.

Example: https://github.com/ivan-zaitsev/java-spring-example/tree/main/isolated-context

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Intellij Idea as IDE you can generate docs manually.

**View -> Tool windows -> Endpoints** 
On Endpoints tab using right-click generate endpoint for whole project or specific endpoint

Full information: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/openapi.html#create-spec

Answer (score -1):

you can use swagger editor: https://editor.swagger.io/

It allows you to write a json/yaml with your specifications and at the same time you can view the result.

Also, in the upper part there are 2 features, which allow you to generate the code based on the json/yaml made.
For example you can create a spring application with all the endpoints you go to specify in your json/yaml ( server).

But you can also generate HTML. (Client)

Comment: I want to _generate_ the API from the app, not write it myself